# Consigo executar qualquer query no SQL Server sem passar as credenciais, isso é normal?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, segurança

Estava procurando reiniciar o serviço do SQL Server, foi quando descobri uma forma de manipular o banco sem logar no sistema. Veja:

1. Abri o Management Studio.
   [image: Abri o SQL Server]
2. Cancelei a autenticação.

[image: Cancelei autenticação.]

3.Acesso o menu de Exibição > Servidores Registrados. Repare que o Object Explorer está desconectado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4. Minha instância do SQL Server rodando...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

5. Nova Consulta...
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
6. Dropando o banco...
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Enfim, isso é meio estranho, alguém sabe como resolver isso? Afinal se alguém tiver acesso à minha máquina...

Comment: mas voce está a usar credenciais, está a usar "Windows credencials", pois esse servidor local está com setup para usar Windows Credencials. No **Security** > **Login/Authentication**  desse servidor, diga que só quer por palavra-chave e remova o Windows Credentials.

Comment: @balexandre entendo, na verdade é realmente um servidor local, mas costumo usar o SA para logar, especialmente no Visual Studio... 
De qualquer maneira, no Login tem vários usuários, no caso devo deletar quais  deles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sendo um servidor local que está usando as credenciais do seu usuário local, a resposta é **sim**, isto é normal.

Note, porém, que é normal para um ambiente de desenvolvimento usado por um programador ou, no máximo, uma equipe de desenvolvimento ou testes.

Num ambiente de produção, um administrador de banco de dados deverá configurar corretamente as permissões mínimas necessárias para sistemas e usuários que acessam o banco de dados.